# sed read multiple lines for a regex replacement

Tags: regex, sed

I need to get this PCRE regular expression working on sed:

```
(\)\;\s)(INSERT INTO )\`(.*)\` VALUES \(
```

Working example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/6GqZul/1)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sed -E 's/();\s)(INSERT INTO )`(.*)` VALUES (/),\n(/gm;t;d' <<< "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,'something');

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it is throwing an error. So, I added the m flag to another sed expression that I had, it worked fine in sed.js.org
```
-r ':a;N;$!ba;s/\);\nINSERT INTO `(.*)` VALUES \(/),\n(/gm;'
```

However, the following doesn't work on my local bash:
sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/\);\nINSERT INTO `(.*)` VALUES \(/),\n(/gm;' sed1.txt
It just returns the same text, not the amended one.
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,'something');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2,'anything');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3,'everything');

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! I went with -z option which did the trick and even made the pattern match shorter.

Shell script with stdin and stdout examples available on [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/Hnw8GV), a copy is available below for sake of completion.

## Script

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -zE 's/\)\;\nINSERT INTO `(.*)` VALUES \(/),\n(/gm;'
```

Note: Requires higher versions of sed, tested with 4.7, [apparently -z works with 4.2 as well](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62m).

## Example stdin (.sql dump from mysqldump --skip-extended-insert)

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,'something');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2,'anything');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3,'everything');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (4,'everything');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (5,'everything');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (6,'everything');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (7,'everything');
```

## Example stdout

### .sql dump converted to multi-line --extended-insert, currently not supported on mysqldump, despite years of multiple requests

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,'something'),
(2,'anything'),
(3,'everything'),
(4,'everything'),
(5,'everything'),
(6,'everything'),
(7,'everything');
```

Hope this helps.

Kind regards,